# How to fix "Skip checkForUpdatesAndNotify because application is not packed" in electron.js

Tags: electron, auto-update, electron-builder

I'm using "electron-updater" to check for auto-updating Electron application.

Calling "checkForUpdatesAndNotify()" function.

In a console, I get "Skip checkForUpdatesAndNotify because application is not packed".

- mac0S Mojave,
- "electron-updater": "^4.0.6",
- "electron": "^3.0.13",
- "electron-builder": "20.28.1"

  ```
      const {autoUpdater} = require("electron-updater");
      autoUpdater.checkForUpdatesAndNotify();

      autoUpdater.on('checking-for-update', () => {
        console.log('Checking for update...');
      });

      autoUpdater.on('update-available', (info) => {
        console.log('Update available.');
      });

      autoUpdater.on('update-not-available', (info) => {
        console.log('Update not available.');
      });

      autoUpdater.on('error', (err) => {
        console.log('Error in auto-updater. ' + err);
      });

      autoUpdater.on('download-progress', (progressObj) => {
        let log_message = "Download speed: " + progressObj.bytesPerSecond;
        log_message = log_message + ' - Downloaded ' + progressObj.percent + '%';
        log_message = log_message + ' (' + progressObj.transferred + "/" + progressObj.total + ')';
        console.log(log_message);
      });

      autoUpdater.on('update-downloaded', (info) => {
        console.log('Update downloaded');
      });
  ```

Comment: In which environment you are facing this issue, development or production?

Answer (score 16):

`checkForUpdatesAndNotify()` just won't work in development mode.

If you insist on test it in dev mode, you can do some hack with `isPackaged`:

```js
const app = require('electron').app;

Object.defineProperty(app, 'isPackaged', {
  get() {
    return true;
  }
});
```

Be careful, do not use this hack for production, it may

Comment: Nice trick! Thanks a lot, it does the job perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

use `autoUpdater.checkForUpdates` instead

Comment: The error still persists

Comment: Same message. "Skip checkForUpdates because application is not packed and dev update config is not forced"